# MOSS 2007 & FIPS Compliance

Tags: 2007, windows-server

I'm looking to set up MOSS 2007 (unfortunately we can't use 2010) in a FIPS-compliant way. We will be using Server 2008 (or R2) in FIPS compliance mode and will be using SQL 2008 with TDE and FIPS-Compliance.

I've tried to read around on the subject but haven't found much.

[This post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33333068/fips-and-sharepoint-resolved.aspx) on Egghead cafe seems to suggest that I need to do the following:

- Install MOSS 2007
- Install all updates, patches, etc. to ensure the latest version (which includes FIPS cryptography)
- Update the machineKey setting to use the 3DES algorithm.
- Create the SharePoint site.

Is there more to it than this, or any pitfalls I might need to avoid? I am relatively new to SharePoint installations and am trying to beef up a little bit before jumping in.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give! I love the StackExchange network sites and hope SharePoint Overflow can once again help enlighten me :)

All the best,
Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for new or existing deployments.

Ensure you have Windows FIPS settings configured either thru GP or Reg.

Update config files with this line:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/>
```

Force a policy update and restart IIS.

SharePoint will work in a FIPS compliant configuration without WorkFlows.

Windows Workflow Foundation doesn't support 3DES encryption and so workflows will error out.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000371